# Can Hive handle multiple double quotes in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, hive

I have a CSV file with embedded commas that I want to drop in a Hive directory so my Hive table will immediately see the data.  I don't wish to pre-process the data, and the data has some consecutive double quotes. e.g.:

```
"hi,there",999,""BROWN,FOX"","goodbye"
```

I know I need to create my table using the CSV SerDe, and I have:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

but when I select the data for this sample data, I get this:

```
hive> select * from my_table;
hi,there    999    "BROWN    FOX"    goodbye
```

instead of what I want:

```
hive> select * from my_table;
hi,there    999    "BROWN,FOX"    goodbye
```

or even:

```
hive> select * from my_table;
hi,there    999    BROWN,FOX    goodbye
```

How do I get Hive to consider double double-quotes as a single double-quote, or otherwise read this data the way I want?  Can I do this without pre-processing the data?  Thank you in advance.